# Testing Facebook Comments Plugin Locally

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-comments

I'm adding the Facebook Comments plugin to a site I'm building on my localhost that has a domain similar to: http://subdomain.domain.lom/

I've added the required code to the page and the plugin appears correctly and I can add comments. The only thing is that it displays a warning message:

> Warning: http://subdomain.domain.lom/path is unreachable

I've also added the moderation `<meta>` tag to the head of my site:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{APP-ID}"/>
```

But when I login to the Facebook comment moderation tool, I don't see any of the test comments I've added.

Is this because I'm testing locally? If so, is there a way I can get the moderation working while developing locally?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to fake facebook into believing this is local.  Since comments are based upon a distinct URL, then give it a url to the real website (but to a fake page).

So if your production page is `http://www.example.com/examplesAndHowTos.php` then do `http://www.example.com/examplesAndHowTos.php?id=test` for the comments url.  Be sure to place the fb:admins in the production page so when Facebook lints it, it can grab those values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

is your site accessible to the outside world even though it's local?
what's giving you that warning message?

sounds to me that your page is just not accessible to facebook, since it's only available on a local network you are using.

Comment: No, my local site isn't accessible from the outsite world. That's what I'm trying to get around, is there a way to enable moderation without the site being accessible from the outsite world.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "enable moderation"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test it locally, you should use the hostname 'localhost', so that facebook knows it will not be able to reach your page.